# Changing the content of JFrame is slow or am i just do it wrong?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I did this little test:(stripped out all that isn't related to the problem)

```
package de.poller.StorrageBox;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainClass implements KeyListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel1;
    JPanel panel2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass c=new MainClass();
    }

    public MainClass() {
        frame=new JFrame("test");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        frame.addKeyListener(this);

        panel1=new JPanel();
        JButton butt1=new JButton("test1111");
        panel1.add(butt1);

        panel2=new JPanel();
        JButton butt2=new JButton("test222");
        panel2.add(butt2);

        frame.add(panel1);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.requestFocus();

    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

        if(arg0.getKeyChar()=='a') {
            activate1();
            val();
        }
        if(arg0.getKeyChar()=='b') {
            activate2();
            val();
        }
    }

    private void activate2() {
        frame.remove(panel1);
        frame.add(panel2);
    }

    private void activate1() {
        frame.remove(panel2);
        frame.add(panel1);
    }

    private void val() {
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.requestFocus();
    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {}


    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}

}
```

The first change from panel 1 to 2 is ok, but if I switch back to 1 it takes a pretty long time(more time than I want the user to have wait) and this is only a panel with 1 single button. No full gui that is planned.

The question here is: is the re-validating (I think it's this process) so slow or am I doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: Rather than removing and adding like you are doing, you should use a CardLayout

Comment: try adding frame.repaint() after frame.revalidate() it may just be a question of a delay in repainting

Comment: didnt hear of cardLayout ever  before(well awt is rather new for me)
worked perfect. thank you a lot. i pin my working code as another answer onto for future. 
thank you a lot

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to ControllAltDel the solution:

(CardLayout)

```
package de.poller.StorrageBox;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainClass implements KeyListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;

    JPanel panel1;
    JPanel panel2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass c=new MainClass();
    }

    public MainClass() {
        frame=new JFrame("test");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        frame.addKeyListener(this);

        panel=new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        frame.add(panel);

        panel1=new JPanel();
        JButton butt1=new JButton("test1111");
        panel1.add(butt1);

        panel2=new JPanel();
        JButton butt2=new JButton("test222");
        panel2.add(butt2);

        panel.add(panel1,"1");
        panel.add(panel2,"2");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.requestFocus();

    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

        if(arg0.getKeyChar()=='a') {
            activate1();
        }
        if(arg0.getKeyChar()=='b') {
            activate2();
        }
    }

    private void activate2() {
        CardLayout cl=(CardLayout)(panel.getLayout());
        cl.show(panel, "2");
    }

    private void activate1() {
        CardLayout cl=(CardLayout)(panel.getLayout());
        cl.show(panel, "1");
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}

}
```

Comment: Rather then using `KeyListener`, which has focus related issues, you're really going to want to have a look at key bindings, which will help solve that problem and present a more reusable framework

Comment: have you any further informations about?(i am just a hobby guy) a bunch of "keywords" or links would help me a lot to improve.

Comment: Do a quick goggle search using "Java key bindings", the first link should give you some good ideas